# Use Task.Run with Synchronous method inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to find a best possible approach to RUN synchronous C# method parallel. For this I opted for `Task.Run()` inside a foreach loop. ie, Add all the synchronous methods to tasks and use `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait()` to perform all the tasks parallel.

Sorry if I am using `Task` without its actual purpose. I am doing this because `DBContext` is NOT thread safe and I have `Mandatory` to use single DBContext per Transaction/DB record. So, I thought making my method `async` is not useful as all the tasks i perform inside a method are dependent to one another. So, I thought its better RUN list of same tasks simultaneously.

NOTE: I ran this program and I can see the Tasks run in parallel without any issue and the records created aren't sequential. So, Its confirmed that the tasks can parallel.

Please help me to suggest whether my implementation is OK for long run.

**Code**

```
    public void MainMethod()
    {
        foreach (var x in _ListUser)
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Update1Record(x)));
        Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
    }
    public string Update1Record(UserViewModel objUser)
    {
        using (var VibrantDbContext = new VIBRANT())
        using (var AuditDb = new VibrantAuditEntities())
        using (var VibrantTransaction = VibrantDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        using (var AuditTransaction = AuditDb.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            try
            {
                VibrantDbContext.Database.Initialize(force: false);
                AuditDb.Database.Initialize(force: false);
                VibrantDbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                var _ObjUserItem = FillupDateTimeValues(objUser);
                ImportToDB(_ObjUserItem, 0, VibrantDbContext, AuditDb);
                BuildImportLog(objUser, VibrantDbContext, AuditDb);
                VibrantDbContext.SaveChanges();
                AuditDb.SaveChanges();
                VibrantTransaction.Commit();
                AuditTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                VibrantTransaction.Rollback();
                AuditTransaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
        return "S";
    }
```

Comment: If your list is huge then you might be better of with bulk update/insert for DB. If your list is not too big then just using a single DB connection might be better. Creating multiple connections would probably cause issues and later during the actual DB update there any ways has to be a lock on the table

Comment: @peeyushsingh: bulk insert/update is not possible as I need to maintain a transaction for each DB entry.

Comment: Why would you not use `Task.WaitAll` instead of what you have used `Task.WhenAll`, which provides a representative task

Comment: Why do you need a transaction per entry?

Comment: I have a bunch of inserts. ie, User, Phone, Email, Address. I wrap all these table entries into a single Transaction. If in a import of say 100 records if 1 fails then it still successfully import 499 records else if i make a single transaction of 500 records then ALL will be failed and none of the records gets stored in the DB.

Answer (score -1):

There is a PARALLEL foreach that you can use in this case. You can see this post for more information:

[Parallel foreach documentation](http://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/parallel-foreach-method-csharp/)

Comment: Please don't link to other sites as an answer. Please put the content in the answer and only link to support what you've presented.

Comment: Bare minimum you shall provide details how shall this API be used in a given code provided by the OP